# Pandas: Getting "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" while trying to merge data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After renaming a `DataFrame`'s column(s), I get an error when merging on the new column(s):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [3, 1]})

df1.columns = [['b']]

df1.merge(df2, on='b')
```

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: what does `df` look like?

Comment: i tried the same in my home PC and i didnt face this issue. let me try and do it tomorrow and post it

Comment: Replaced the below code 
tmp.columns = [['POR','POR_PORT']]
with
tmp.rename(columns={'Locode':'POR', 'Port Name':'POR_PORT'}, inplace=True)
and it worked. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replaced the code `tmp.columns = [['POR','POR_PORT']]` with `tmp.rename(columns={'Locode':'POR', 'Port Name':'POR_PORT'}, inplace=True)` and it worked.

Answer (score 23):

When renaming columns, use `DataFrame.columns = [list]`, not `DataFrame.columns = [[list]]`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [3, 1]})

df1.columns = ['b']

df1.merge(df2, on='b')
#   b
# 0 1
```

Comment: You have no idea how frustrating this was for like a solid hour. Thank you. this worked.