# In pandas, what is the difference between [list] and [[list]]?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sorry if this question is already answered, but I truly don't know the different names of either of those (object or list or array?), so I am still confused.

I'm just curious as a follow up from this question.

[Pandas: Getting "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" while trying to merge data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59879577/pandas-getting-typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted-to-a-sca)

And the answer by [Ilyas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59906739/5143122).

Why `[[list]]` resulted in an error

> only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

but `[list]` doesn't?

Comment: `['a']` is a list of strings (presumably) and `[['a']]` is a list of a list of strings. Why would one be a valid substitute for the other? If I index into that list expecting a string and instead get a list then a TypeError is the most likely and easily debugged outcome.

Comment: I see. Thank you! I've only realised this now.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant code you talk about in the linked question is:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [3, 1]})

df1.columns = [['b']] # WRONG
df1.columns = ['b']   # CORRECT

df1.merge(df2, on='b')
```

`df.columns` must be a list of *column labels*<sup>1</sup>, each representing the name of a column. In the wrong version, you're setting it to be a one-element list whose element is itself a list (NOT a string), and thus the error.

---

<sub>1 *column labels* is straight from the [documentation of `DataFrame.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html), strings are a type of valid values (although not the only one, see the comments below). Lists, on the other hand, generate a MultiIndex (try `print (df1.columns)` after the "wrong" version), which causes problems later in the call to `merge`.</sub>

Comment: *`df.columns` must be a list of strings, each representing the name of a column.* Not true...Try `df1.columns = [('a',)]`

Comment: Fair point, I wasn't quite sure whether other hashable types would be allowed. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) talks about "column labels", but I guess that is broader than strings. I'll adapt the answer

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! I get it now. ^_^

Comment: `df1.columns = [['b']]` this doesn't give an error it converts `[['b']]` to `MultiIndex`, This error is related to `merge` **not** `df.columns`.

Comment: @Ch3steR isn't `merge` failing because it uses `['b']` under the hood to try indexing in the dataframe (is `columns` a property with a setter that does the conversion to multiindex, or are we overwriting a list and facing consequences later on? I couldn't find any information about this)? Setting `columns` is not in itself raising the error, but it's the source of it.

Comment: After digging in the docs in `pandas/merge.py` `_MergeOperation` class has a function `get_results` which calls `_get_merge_keys` which inturn calls `_get_label_or_level_values` which calls `xs` on `df1`(in this case) is what is generating the error. Try this `df1.columns = [['b']]; df1.xs('b',axis=1)` getting the same error. (Same traceback with same func calls)

Comment: @Ch3steR Indeed. I looked for the setter of `columns`, which I didn't find in `pandas/core/frame.py` and I can't quite find anywhere else. Either way, setting both `df1` and `df2` to have MultiIndexes still causes problems on `merge` (I tried with multiple versions of the `on` attribute, ofc). My take on this is: keep the columns simple. The docs for this could definitely use some additional love.

Comment: `df1.columns =[['b']]; df2.columns = [['b']]; df1.merge(df2, on = [('b',)],how='outer')` gives correct output. Since OP is converting `df1.columns` to `MultiIndex` and `df2.columns` is `Index`....`df.xs` is raising error i guess.